# SQL Server Table partitioning

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have some old project which has multiple databases with same structure. There is database for each language supported, so I have 4 databases with same structure. I think this is not efficient and it's hard to support and make updates to databases, so I want to create one database which will have new table `Languages` with columns `id` and `code` and for each table add foreign key to this table. It should work well, but I also would like to partition every table to separate filegroup based on language.

So for example I have old table `Customers` with structure `(id, name, surname, data)`, so in new database it will have `(id, name, surname, data, langId)`.

So I want to have something like `customer_eng, customer_de, customer_it` filegroups based on langId.

Is it possible to do? I have found partitioning function and scheme, but there are only possibility to define some range values, but I don't need ranges, I want to group data to separate files based on langId, that's all what I want to do. If it's possible I would like to make it dynamic, so when new langId (new language added) is added it will automatically create new file for this language.

Comment: consider asking this here http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Although SQL Server technically provides only range partitioning, you can accomplish the desired result by specifying the desired list as a range.  You can also add a check constraint to match the list to ensure only exact values are inserted, although that is not needed in this case due to the foreign key to the Languages table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the separate partitions using ranges, by doing something like this:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION MyPartitionFunction (varchar(255))
AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES ('de', 'eng', 'it');
```

However, I would suggest using the actual ids instead:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION MyPartitionFunction (int)
AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

Comment: but is there a possibility to make it dynamic? I know that it's possible to have some workaround like adding the insert trigger to Languages table and then alter all the partitioning functions to new values, but is it the only solution?

Comment: Search for "sql server dynamic partitioning".  Here are two results:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842764/how-to-dynamically-declare-partition-range-in-partition-function-in-sql-server and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842764/how-to-dynamically-declare-partition-range-in-partition-function-in-sql-server.

Comment: For those who doesn't know: partitioning is supported only by enterprise version of sql server (what a bummer)